# Unable to get head of dask dataframe gotten from csv file

Tags: dask-distributed, dask-dataframe

If I get a dask dataframe through read_csv function, inside a LocalCluster, this dask dataframe can't be computed properly.

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
from dask.distributed import Client, LocalCluster
import pandas as pd

local_file = 'example.csv'
df0 = pd.DataFrame({'id':[0,1,3], 'model':['A', 'B', 'C']})
df0.to_csv(local_file)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with LocalCluster(processes=False) as cluster, Client(cluster) as client: 
        df = dd.read_csv(local_file)
        print('df :')
        print(df.compute())
        # df.head()
```

What I get :

```
df :
0    (<Serialize: subgraph_callable-f850d381-6329-4...
dtype: object
```

If I compute  df.head() :

```
2023-03-07 18:25:15,687 - distributed.worker - WARNING - Compute Failed
Key:       ('head-1-5-read-csv-846b254fb00d0eef448f963991dd89f8', 0)
Function:  head
args:      ((<Serialize: subgraph_callable-0b198265-fa68-40d8-84f9-4822ad39f740>, <Serialize: [(<function read_block_from_file at 0x7f3c1c9400d0>, <OpenFile '/home/fcs/example.csv'>, 0, 28, b'\n'), None, True, True]>), 5)
kwargs:    {}
Exception: 'AttributeError("\'tuple\' object has no attribute \'head\'")'

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File ~/miniconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/spyder_kernels/py3compat.py:356 in compat_exec
    exec(code, globals, locals)

  File ~/230303_OLYMP_WHERE/untitled0.py:22
    df.head()

  File ~/miniconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dask/dataframe/core.py:1390 in head
    return self._head(n=n, npartitions=npartitions, compute=compute, safe=safe)

  File ~/miniconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dask/dataframe/core.py:1424 in _head
    result = result.compute()

  File ~/miniconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dask/base.py:314 in compute
    (result,) = compute(self, traverse=False, **kwargs)

  File ~/miniconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dask/base.py:599 in compute
    results = schedule(dsk, keys, **kwargs)

  File ~/miniconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/distributed/client.py:3136 in get
    results = self.gather(packed, asynchronous=asynchronous, direct=direct)

  File ~/miniconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/distributed/client.py:2305 in gather
    return self.sync(

  File ~/miniconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/distributed/utils.py:338 in sync
    return sync(

  File ~/miniconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/distributed/utils.py:405 in sync
    raise exc.with_traceback(tb)

  File ~/miniconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/distributed/utils.py:378 in f
    result = yield future

  File ~/miniconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tornado/gen.py:769 in run
    value = future.result()

  File ~/miniconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/distributed/client.py:2168 in _gather
    raise exception.with_traceback(traceback)

  File ~/miniconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dask/utils.py:1105 in __call__
    return getattr(__obj, self.method)(*args, **kwargs)

AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'head'
```

working on Ubuntu - 20.04 LTS (WSL2 under windows 11) on conda envt :

```
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
_libgcc_mutex             0.1                        main
_openmp_mutex             5.1                       1_gnu
alabaster                 0.7.12             pyhd3eb1b0_0
appdirs                   1.4.4              pyhd3eb1b0_0
arrow                     1.2.3           py310h06a4308_1
astroid                   2.14.2          py310h06a4308_0
asttokens                 2.0.5              pyhd3eb1b0_0
atomicwrites              1.4.0                      py_0
attrs                     22.1.0          py310h06a4308_0
autopep8                  1.6.0              pyhd3eb1b0_1
babel                     2.11.0          py310h06a4308_0
backcall                  0.2.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
beautifulsoup4            4.11.1          py310h06a4308_0
binaryornot               0.4.4              pyhd3eb1b0_1
black                     22.6.0          py310h06a4308_0
blas                      1.0                         mkl
bleach                    4.1.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
bokeh                     2.4.3              pyhd8ed1ab_3    conda-forge
bottleneck                1.3.5           py310ha9d4c09_0
brotlipy                  0.7.0           py310h7f8727e_1002
bzip2                     1.0.8                h7b6447c_0
ca-certificates           2022.12.7            ha878542_0    conda-forge
certifi                   2022.12.7          pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
cffi                      1.15.1          py310h5eee18b_3
chardet                   4.0.0           py310h06a4308_1003
charset-normalizer        2.0.4              pyhd3eb1b0_0
click                     8.0.4           py310h06a4308_0
cloudpickle               2.0.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
colorama                  0.4.6           py310h06a4308_0
comm                      0.1.2           py310h06a4308_0
conda                     23.1.0          py310hff52083_0    conda-forge
conda-content-trust       0.1.3           py310h06a4308_0
conda-package-handling    2.0.2           py310h06a4308_0
conda-package-streaming   0.7.0           py310h06a4308_0
cookiecutter              1.7.3              pyhd3eb1b0_0
cryptography              39.0.1          py310h9ce1e76_0
cytoolz                   0.12.0          py310h5eee18b_0
dask                      2023.3.0           pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
dask-core                 2023.3.0           pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
dbus                      1.13.18              hb2f20db_0
debugpy                   1.5.1           py310h295c915_0
decorator                 5.1.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0
defusedxml                0.7.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0
diff-match-patch          20200713           pyhd3eb1b0_0
dill                      0.3.6           py310h06a4308_0
distributed               2023.3.0           pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
docstring-to-markdown     0.11            py310h06a4308_0
docutils                  0.18.1          py310h06a4308_3
entrypoints               0.4             py310h06a4308_0
et_xmlfile                1.1.0           py310h06a4308_0
executing                 0.8.3              pyhd3eb1b0_0
expat                     2.4.9                h6a678d5_0
flake8                    6.0.0           py310h06a4308_0
flit-core                 3.6.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
fontconfig                2.14.1               h52c9d5c_1
freetype                  2.12.1               h4a9f257_0
fsspec                    2023.1.0           pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
giflib                    5.2.1                h5eee18b_3
glib                      2.69.1               he621ea3_2
gst-plugins-base          1.14.1               h6a678d5_1
gstreamer                 1.14.1               h5eee18b_1
heapdict                  1.0.1                      py_0    conda-forge
icu                       58.2                 he6710b0_3
idna                      3.4             py310h06a4308_0
imagesize                 1.4.1           py310h06a4308_0
importlib-metadata        4.11.3          py310h06a4308_0
importlib_metadata        4.11.3               hd3eb1b0_0
inflection                0.5.1           py310h06a4308_0
intel-openmp              2021.4.0          h06a4308_3561
intervaltree              3.1.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
ipykernel                 6.19.2          py310h2f386ee_0
ipython                   8.10.0          py310h06a4308_0
ipython_genutils          0.2.0              pyhd3eb1b0_1
isort                     5.9.3              pyhd3eb1b0_0
jedi                      0.18.1          py310h06a4308_1
jeepney                   0.7.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0
jellyfish                 0.9.0           py310h7f8727e_0
jinja2                    3.1.2           py310h06a4308_0
jinja2-time               0.2.0              pyhd3eb1b0_3
jpeg                      9e                   h7f8727e_0
jsonschema                4.17.3          py310h06a4308_0
jupyter_client            7.4.9           py310h06a4308_0
jupyter_core              5.2.0           py310h06a4308_0
jupyterlab_pygments       0.1.2                      py_0
keyring                   23.4.0          py310h06a4308_0
krb5                      1.19.4               h568e23c_0
lazy-object-proxy         1.6.0           py310h7f8727e_0
lcms2                     2.12                 h3be6417_0
ld_impl_linux-64          2.38                 h1181459_1
lerc                      3.0                  h295c915_0
libclang                  10.0.1          default_hb85057a_2
libdeflate                1.17                 h5eee18b_0
libedit                   3.1.20221030         h5eee18b_0
libevent                  2.1.12               h8f2d780_0
libffi                    3.4.2                h6a678d5_6
libgcc-ng                 11.2.0               h1234567_1
libgfortran-ng            11.2.0               h00389a5_1
libgfortran5              11.2.0               h1234567_1
libgomp                   11.2.0               h1234567_1
libllvm10                 10.0.1               hbcb73fb_5
libpng                    1.6.37               hbc83047_0
libpq                     12.9                 h16c4e8d_3
libsodium                 1.0.18               h7b6447c_0
libspatialindex           1.9.3                h2531618_0
libstdcxx-ng              11.2.0               h1234567_1
libtiff                   4.5.0                h6a678d5_2
libuuid                   1.41.5               h5eee18b_0
libwebp                   1.2.4                h11a3e52_1
libwebp-base              1.2.4                h5eee18b_1
libxcb                    1.15                 h7f8727e_0
libxkbcommon              1.0.1                hfa300c1_0
libxml2                   2.9.14               h74e7548_0
libxslt                   1.1.35               h4e12654_0
locket                    1.0.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
lxml                      4.9.1           py310h1edc446_0
lz4                       3.1.3           py310h7f8727e_0
lz4-c                     1.9.4                h6a678d5_0
markupsafe                2.1.1           py310h7f8727e_0
matplotlib-inline         0.1.6           py310h06a4308_0
mccabe                    0.7.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
mistune                   0.8.4           py310h7f8727e_1000
mkl                       2021.4.0           h06a4308_640
mkl-service               2.4.0           py310h7f8727e_0
mkl_fft                   1.3.1           py310hd6ae3a3_0
mkl_random                1.2.2           py310h00e6091_0
msgpack-python            1.0.3           py310hd09550d_0
mypy_extensions           0.4.3           py310h06a4308_0
nbclient                  0.5.13          py310h06a4308_0
nbconvert                 6.5.4           py310h06a4308_0
nbformat                  5.7.0           py310h06a4308_0
ncurses                   6.4                  h6a678d5_0
nest-asyncio              1.5.6           py310h06a4308_0
nspr                      4.33                 h295c915_0
nss                       3.74                 h0370c37_0
numexpr                   2.8.4           py310h8879344_0
numpy                     1.23.5          py310hd5efca6_0
numpy-base                1.23.5          py310h8e6c178_0
numpydoc                  1.5.0           py310h06a4308_0
openpyxl                  3.0.10          py310h5eee18b_0
openssl                   1.1.1t               h7f8727e_0
packaging                 22.0            py310h06a4308_0
pandas                    1.5.2           py310h1128e8f_0
pandocfilters             1.5.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
parso                     0.8.3              pyhd3eb1b0_0
partd                     1.3.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pathspec                  0.10.3          py310h06a4308_0
pcre                      8.45                 h295c915_0
pexpect                   4.8.0              pyhd3eb1b0_3
pickleshare               0.7.5           pyhd3eb1b0_1003
pillow                    9.4.0           py310h6a678d5_0
pip                       22.3.1          py310h06a4308_0
platformdirs              2.5.2           py310h06a4308_0
pluggy                    1.0.0           py310h06a4308_1
ply                       3.11            py310h06a4308_0
pooch                     1.4.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
poyo                      0.5.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
prompt-toolkit            3.0.36          py310h06a4308_0
psutil                    5.9.0           py310h5eee18b_0
ptyprocess                0.7.0              pyhd3eb1b0_2
pure_eval                 0.2.2              pyhd3eb1b0_0
pycodestyle               2.10.0          py310h06a4308_0
pycosat                   0.6.4           py310h5eee18b_0
pycparser                 2.21               pyhd3eb1b0_0
pydocstyle                6.3.0           py310h06a4308_0
pyflakes                  3.0.1           py310h06a4308_0
pygments                  2.11.2             pyhd3eb1b0_0
pylint                    2.16.2          py310h06a4308_0
pylint-venv               2.3.0           py310h06a4308_0
pyls-spyder               0.4.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
pyopenssl                 23.0.0          py310h06a4308_0
pyqt                      5.15.7          py310h6a678d5_1
pyqt5-sip                 12.11.0                  pypi_0    pypi
pyqtwebengine             5.15.7          py310h6a678d5_1
pyrsistent                0.18.0          py310h7f8727e_0
pysocks                   1.7.1           py310h06a4308_0
python                    3.10.9               h7a1cb2a_0
python-dateutil           2.8.2              pyhd3eb1b0_0
python-fastjsonschema     2.16.2          py310h06a4308_0
python-lsp-black          1.2.1           py310h06a4308_0
python-lsp-jsonrpc        1.0.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
python-lsp-server         1.7.1           py310h06a4308_0
python-slugify            5.0.2              pyhd3eb1b0_0
python_abi                3.10                    2_cp310    conda-forge
pytoolconfig              1.2.5           py310h06a4308_1
pytz                      2022.7          py310h06a4308_0
pyxdg                     0.27               pyhd3eb1b0_0
pyyaml                    6.0             py310h5eee18b_1
pyzmq                     23.2.0          py310h6a678d5_0
qdarkstyle                3.0.2              pyhd3eb1b0_0
qstylizer                 0.2.2           py310h06a4308_0
qt-main                   5.15.2               h327a75a_7
qt-webengine              5.15.9               hd2b0992_4
qtawesome                 1.2.2           py310h06a4308_0
qtconsole                 5.4.0           py310h06a4308_0
qtpy                      2.2.0           py310h06a4308_0
qtwebkit                  5.212                h4eab89a_4
readline                  8.2                  h5eee18b_0
requests                  2.28.1          py310h06a4308_0
rope                      1.7.0           py310h06a4308_0
rtree                     1.0.1           py310h06a4308_0
ruamel.yaml               0.17.21         py310h5eee18b_0
ruamel.yaml.clib          0.2.6           py310h5eee18b_1
scipy                     1.10.0          py310hd5efca6_1
secretstorage             3.3.1           py310h06a4308_0
setuptools                65.6.3          py310h06a4308_0
sip                       6.6.2           py310h6a678d5_0
six                       1.16.0             pyhd3eb1b0_1
snowballstemmer           2.2.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
sortedcontainers          2.4.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
soupsieve                 2.3.2.post1     py310h06a4308_0
sphinx                    5.0.2           py310h06a4308_0
sphinxcontrib-applehelp   1.0.2              pyhd3eb1b0_0
sphinxcontrib-devhelp     1.0.2              pyhd3eb1b0_0
sphinxcontrib-htmlhelp    2.0.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
sphinxcontrib-jsmath      1.0.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0
sphinxcontrib-qthelp      1.0.3              pyhd3eb1b0_0
sphinxcontrib-serializinghtml 1.1.5              pyhd3eb1b0_0
spyder                    5.4.1           py310h06a4308_0
spyder-kernels            2.4.1           py310h06a4308_0
sqlite                    3.40.1               h5082296_0
stack_data                0.2.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
tblib                     1.7.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
text-unidecode            1.3                pyhd3eb1b0_0
textdistance              4.2.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0
three-merge               0.1.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0
tinycss2                  1.2.1           py310h06a4308_0
tk                        8.6.12               h1ccaba5_0
toml                      0.10.2             pyhd3eb1b0_0
tomli                     2.0.1           py310h06a4308_0
tomlkit                   0.11.1          py310h06a4308_0
toolz                     0.12.0          py310h06a4308_0
tornado                   6.2             py310h5eee18b_0
tqdm                      4.64.1          py310h06a4308_0
traitlets                 5.7.1           py310h06a4308_0
typing-extensions         4.4.0           py310h06a4308_0
typing_extensions         4.4.0           py310h06a4308_0
tzdata                    2022g                h04d1e81_0
ujson                     5.4.0           py310h6a678d5_0
unidecode                 1.2.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
urllib3                   1.26.14         py310h06a4308_0
watchdog                  2.1.6           py310h06a4308_0
wcwidth                   0.2.5              pyhd3eb1b0_0
webencodings              0.5.1           py310h06a4308_1
whatthepatch              1.0.2           py310h06a4308_0
wheel                     0.37.1             pyhd3eb1b0_0
wrapt                     1.14.1          py310h5eee18b_0
wurlitzer                 3.0.2           py310h06a4308_0
xz                        5.2.10               h5eee18b_1
yaml                      0.2.5                h7b6447c_0
yapf                      0.31.0             pyhd3eb1b0_0
zeromq                    4.3.4                h2531618_0
zict                      2.2.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
zipp                      3.11.0          py310h06a4308_0
zlib                      1.2.13               h5eee18b_0
zstandard                 0.19.0          py310h5eee18b_0
zstd                      1.5.2                ha4553b6_0
```

Outside of the LocalCluster, it works properly.

what I expect :

```
df = dd.read_csv(local_file)
print('df :')
print(df.compute())
df.head()
```

gives :

```
df :
   Unnamed: 0  id model
0           0   0     A
1           1   1     B
2           2   3     C
```

Hope this example is reproducible and you can give me some advice on how to parametrize either the Client or the read_csv function...

Thanks a lot

Comment: This is definitely strange. What is `type(df)`?

Comment: <class 'dask.dataframe.core.DataFrame'>

Comment: And this is the exact code you run? No modifications except uncommenting df.head()?

Comment: Yes. I removed file_path for 'local_file'. 
I got the same trouble with a 2022.10.0 version of Dask on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce the bug with the code snippet that you provided. There seems to be a real issue here with Dask context managers.

A work-around to this is just not to use context manager:

```py
client = Client()
df = dd.read_csv(local_file)
print('df :')
print(df.compute())
df.head()
```

This code is working as expected.